# Securing Spring Boot REST API with AAD and AWS Cognito for different Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

hopefully someone can help me out here, since i cannot find any resources on this topic anywhere.

I have got a Spring Boot RestAPI which is currently configured in a way where there are two kinds of routes: 1. Unauthorized 2. Authorized via Bearer with AAD/Entra

My configure method is currently setup as follows:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/protected/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
        );
}
```

This is wrapped in a class which extends the `AadResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

With our API configured in that way we are able to protect our routes as follows:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('APPROLE_AppName.RoleName')")
@GetMapping(value = "/some-method", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getStrings() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(...);
}
```

Our API now should be extended to also allow a new kind of users to use authorized endpoints. These users are managed by AWS Cognito. How can i setup my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to allow certain paths to be unauthorized, some to be protected via AAD and some via AWS Cognito?

The main problem i seem to have is that the `AadResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configures the Jwt validation in such a way, that it only works with Bearers given out by Microsoft.

Ideally i would like to have something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AzureAdSecurityConfig extends AadResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                    .antMatchers("/api/aad/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            );
            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt([UTILIZE AAD JWT VALIDATION]);
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AwsCognitoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                    .antMatchers("/api/cognito/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            );
            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt([UTILIZE AWS COGNITO JWT VALIDATION]);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class DefaultSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.csrf().disable();
                http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
            }
    }

}
```

Another problem i found is that the `AadResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` automatically sets all possible prefixes to "SCOPE_" and "APPROLE_" for the JwtClaimNames "roles" and "scp". Ideally i would like them to be different for AAD and AWS Cognito in such a way that i would have "AAD_SCOPE_", "AAD_APPROLE_" and "COGNITO_GROUP_" as the prefixes.

I found some sources which explain on how to implement multi-tenant Jwt validation for Spring Boot, but they all implement password/user based authentication with a SQL database only.

Is there a way around basically having to re-implement all the AAD logic, so that i can mix in validation for the Jwt given out by AWS Cognito, or is there a way to decide on a route basis?

I already know that you can use the `oauth2ResourceServer()` function on the `HttpSecurity` to configure Jwt usage, but i found only information on how to implement that for a single tenant.

If someone has already successfully implemented this specific or a similar case, or can nudge me into the right direction i would highly appreciate it.
Or maybe the way i am thinking about is completely wrong, then please let me know.

## UPDATE (25. Jan. 2024) with working solution

Thanks to the answer of [@ch4mp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619830/ch4mp) i've got it working. >[Working Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77868927/4015150)<

Now my implementation is highly simplified and looks as follows:

application.yml

```yaml
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
          - iss: https://cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<cognito-pool>
            authorities:
              - path: $.cognito:groups
                prefix: COGNITO_GROUP_
          - iss: https://sts.windows.net/<entra objectid>/
            authorities:
              - path: $.roles.*
                prefix: AAD_APPROLE_
              - path: $.scp
                prefix: AAD_SCOPE_
            aud: <enterprise application id>
        resource-server:
          permit-all:
            - /api/route/noauth
```

SecurityConfig

```java
package some.package;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig { }
```

And my controller now looks like this:

```java
package some.package;


import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/route")
public class JwtTestController {

    @GetMapping("/aadauth")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AAD_APPROLE_GrantedApprole.XXX')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> aadauthRole() {
        Jwt jwt = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwt.getClaims().toString());
    }

    @GetMapping("/aadauth")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AAD_SCOPE_GrantedScope.XXX')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> aadauthScope() {
        Jwt jwt = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwt.getClaims().toString());
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('COGNITO_GROUP_SomeGroup')")
    @GetMapping("/cognitoauth")
    public ResponseEntity<String> cognitoauth() {
        Jwt jwt = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(jwt.getClaims().toString());
    }

    @GetMapping("/noauth")
    public ResponseEntity<String> noauth() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'com.c4-soft.springaddons:spring-addons-starter-oidc:7.3.5'
```

This is *not* an official starter for Spring, but rather an OSS implementation: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons

If i run into any other issues with it i will update once again, but as for now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expose here a solution using [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) because it is much easier.

If you prefer to build the security conf using just "official" Spring Boot starters, you'll have to provide your own `AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest>` using `iss` claim, each authentication manager having its own authentication converter with its own authorities converter to handle the source claims and the prefixes you want. Browse through [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) or [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html) to get samples and implementation hints. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77868535/619830) can be of help too (quite different authorities mapping requirements but similar authentication manager resolver).

#### With Boot `3.2.2` and spring-addons

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-tenant-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-addons.version>7.3.5</spring-addons.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-addons.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-addons.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConf {
}
```

Edit the following `application.yaml` to put your own issuers:

```yaml
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_RzhmgLwjl
          authorities:
          - path: $.cognito:groups
            prefix: COGNITO_GROUP_
        - iss: https://sts.windows.net/0a962d63-6b23-4416-81a6-29f88c553998/
          authorities:
          - path: $.appRoles.*.displayName
            prefix: AAD_APPROLE_
          - path: $.scope
            prefix: AAD_SCOPE_
        resourceserver:
          # spring-addons whitelist is for permitAll() (rather than isAuthenticated())
          # which is probably much safer
          permit-all:
          - /actuator/health/readiness
          - /actuator/health/liveness
          - /v3/api-docs/**
          - /api/public/**
```

The values for `path` above are JSON path. You can use a tool like [jsonpath.com](https://jsonpath.com/) to test your path expressions against your own token payloads (extracted with a tool like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)).

Yes, that easy. No, I did not omit any YAML property or Java configuration (just test in a new project if you don't believe me).

#### Sample Controller

```java
@RestController
public class GreetController {

    @GetMapping("/greet")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String getGreet(Authentication auth) {
        return "Hello %s! You are granted with %s.".formatted(auth.getName(), auth.getAuthorities());
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/strings")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('AAD_APPROLE_Admin', 'COGNITO_GROUP_admin')")
    public List<String> getStrings() {
        return List.of("protected", "strings");
    }
}
```

#### Sample Tests

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = GreetController.class)
@AutoConfigureAddonsWebmvcResourceServerSecurity
@Import(SecurityConf.class)
class GreetControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvcSupport api;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetGreet_thenUnauthorized() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        api.get("/greet").andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("aad_admin.json")
    void givenUserIsAadAdmin_whenGetGreet_thenOk() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        final var actual = api.get("/greet").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(
            "Hello aad-admin! You are granted with [AAD_APPROLE_msiam_access, AAD_APPROLE_Admin, AAD_SCOPE_openid, AAD_SCOPE_profile, AAD_SCOPE_machin:truc].",
            actual);
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("cognito_admin.json")
    void givenUserIsCognitoAdmin_whenGetGreet_thenOk() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        final var actual = api.get("/greet").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals("Hello amazon-cognito-admin! You are granted with [COGNITO_GROUP_admin, COGNITO_GROUP_machin:truc].", actual);
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("aad_machin-truc.json")
    void givenUserIsAadMachinTruc_whenGetGreet_thenOk() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        final var actual = api.get("/greet").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals("Hello aad-user! You are granted with [AAD_APPROLE_msiam_access, AAD_SCOPE_openid, AAD_SCOPE_profile, AAD_SCOPE_machin:truc].", actual);
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("cognito_machin-truc.json")
    void givenUserIsCognitoMachinTruc_whenGetGreet_thenOk() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        final var actual = api.get("/greet").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals("Hello amazon-cognito-user! You are granted with [COGNITO_GROUP_machin:truc].", actual);
    }

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetStrings_thenUnauthorized() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        api.get("/strings").andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("aad_admin.json")
    void givenUserIsAadAdmin_whenGetStrings_thenOk() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        final var actual = api.get("/strings").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals("[\"protected\",\"strings\"]", actual);
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("cognito_admin.json")
    void givenUserIsCognitoAdmin_whenGetStrings_thenOk() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        final var actual = api.get("/strings").andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals("[\"protected\",\"strings\"]", actual);
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("aad_machin-truc.json")
    void givenUserIsAadMachinTruc_whenGetStrings_thenForbidden() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        api.get("/strings").andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("cognito_machin-truc.json")
    void givenUserIsCognitoMachinTruc_whenGetStrings_thenForbidden() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, Exception {
        api.get("/strings").andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

}
```

With this test resources:

- `aad_admin.json`

```json
{
    "sub": "aad-admin",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/0a962d63-6b23-4416-81a6-29f88c553998/",
    "appRoles": [
        {
          "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
          ],
          "description": "msiam_access",
          "displayName": "msiam_access",
          "id": "ef7437e6-4f94-4a0a-a110-a439eb2aa8f7",
          "isEnabled": true,
          "origin": "Application",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
          ],
          "description": "Administrators Only",
          "displayName": "Admin",
          "id": "4f8f8640-f081-492d-97a0-caf24e9bc134",
          "isEnabled": true,
          "origin": "ServicePrincipal",
          "value": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "scope": "openid profile machin:truc"
}
```

- `aad_machin-truc.json`

```json
{
    "sub": "aad-user",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/0a962d63-6b23-4416-81a6-29f88c553998/",
    "appRoles": [
        {
          "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
          ],
          "description": "msiam_access",
          "displayName": "msiam_access",
          "id": "ef7437e6-4f94-4a0a-a110-a439eb2aa8f7",
          "isEnabled": true,
          "origin": "Application",
          "value": null
        }
    ],
    "scope": "openid profile machin:truc"
}
```

- `cognito_admin.json`

```json
{
    "sub": "amazon-cognito-admin",
    "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_RzhmgLwjl",
    "cognito:groups": ["admin", "machin:truc"],
    "scope": "openid profile cog:scope"
}
```

- `cognito_machin-truc.json`

```json
{
    "sub": "amazon-cognito-user",
    "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_RzhmgLwjl",
    "cognito:groups": ["machin:truc"],
    "scope": "openid profile cog:scope"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into that more specific tomorrow. I will give an update once i have tested around with implementing it!

Comment: After first having to update Spring Boot to version 3, Java to Version 21, etc. etc. i finally was able to follow your guidance. It worked! Thanks so much. There are few things i had to change though. First thing was adding the "aud" to the application.yml, so it would only accept tokens of users who have access to a specific enterprise application. Second thing is, that "resourceserver" had to be changed to "resource-server" for me to work. Third is, that the paths for AAD were wrong. I have changed them to "$.roles.*" and "$.scp". Now everything is working as i want it though. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of [spring-addons-starter-oidc](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.c4-soft.springaddons/spring-addons-starter-oidc/versions) did you pick?

Comment: i used version 7.3.5.

Comment: Then it is strange that you have to use `resource-server` because [the property](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/990a8ca4e1e15f6c9eb0dcd657a50d968bab1b2d/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/properties/SpringAddonsOidcProperties.java#L54) has long been named `resourceserver`. Also be aware that, of course, you should align your test payloads with actual tokens structures (you don't need all claims, but you surely need the values you use in your security conf and expressions to have the same JSON path)

Comment: Of course I already tested this with an actual token. That’s why I noticed, that the json path expression doesn’t line up with how the tokens issued by Microsoft look like. I’m getting the tokens with MSAL btw.